# Jar to exe woes, classpath understanding

Tags: java, jar, classpath, exe

I thought I had a grasp on things but apparently not.

So I use javac to turn .java into .class

`javac KFile.java`

I then jar to turn the class file into a jar file

`jar cf HPLCData.jar KFile.class`

I then wrapped the .jar file with launch4j, specifically keeping 'don't wrap jar' unchecked to provide me with `HPLCData.exe`.

From the command line, if I run the code with `java KFile` it works like a charm.  If I run HPLCData.exe, I get this run time error, which seems to be associated with my directory scanner.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.langNoClassDefFoundError: KFile$1
    at KFile.addTree(KFile.java:162)
    at KFile.main(KFile.java:48)
Caused by java.lank.ClassNotFoundEception: KFile$1
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass*Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unkonwon Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    .... 2 more
```

To me, it seems like the error is something I am doing since if I run the java script itself it works fine, however, here is that portion of the code below.  I just thought that if I make a jar file that has the class in it, how can the .exe that wraps the jar file not find the class?

```
static void addTree(Path directory, final Collection<Path> all)
    throws IOException {
Files.walkFileTree(directory, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
            throws IOException {
        all.add(file);
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
});
```

## EDIT

For what it's worth, I thought I was crazy because sometimes the .exe file would work in the original directory where my .jar and .class files were.  I thought they had something to do with it, but I started noticing that when it works, I can visually see the creation of a KFile$1.class file.

I left this out because, honestly, it makes me sound like a nutter and I can't reproduce it now.

Oh interesting.  KFile$1.class appears when I use
`javac KFile.class`
So let me try just adding those to my jar file then.

Comment: can u run java -jar HPLCData.jar

Comment: `no main manifest attribute, in HPLCData.jar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `.java`-file you seem to be using anonymous inner classes. So your compilation will produce more than one `.class`-file. Besides `KFile.class` there will be `KFile$1.class` and probably `KFile$2.class` etc.

All of those are needed to execute your program but you are only adding `KFile.class` to your jar-file, so all others are not found when executing the application from the jar.

Try `jar cf HPLCData.jar *.class` to include all of the class-files in your current directory (it would be best if there are only those from your current project), then everything should work as expected.

Comment: What you say makes sense, but it must be managed on its own as the directory only has this one class file and some apache commons stuff, but I ended up not using.

Comment: Yes, it works when the .class file is actually there.  It was produced with .javac and I didn't notice when it started doing that.